# In JIRA, how to prevent logging work once an issue has resolution Done?

Tags: jira

I want to prevent my users from logging work once an issue gets to a particular status. How can I accomplish this?

I have a post-function in my workflow that sets the Resolution, but the "Log Work" item in the More menu still shows up.

I don't see in the Project or System administration any options about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can accomplish this by setting jira.issue.editable to false in the properties of the status in the workflow.

1. Find the active workflow that applies to the issues you wish change. This is most easily done by either: going to the 'Workflow Schemes' admin page, then clicking on the Workflow link in the row applying to the issues' project and issue type, or clicking View Workflow in the Issue View.
2. To edit the workflow, you will need to either create a copy of it (if using the default jira system workflow) or edit the draft of the workflow.
3. In the Workflow Editor, for the 'Closed' step, click View Properties (in Text mode) or Properties (in Diagram mode) to see the step properties.
4. Editing issues in the selected step is enabled by default, or you will see a jira.issue.editable property with value true. Either create the value or chang the property value to false.
5. Publish your draft workflow, or if editing a copy, activate the workflow by creating a new workflow scheme associated with the edited workflow, and then associating it with your project.

Reference: https://confluence.atlassian.com/jira/allow-editing-of-closed-issues-138704.html

Comment: Thanks. I discovered the "jira.issue.editable" properly shortly before you answered.